# How to handle scrollable pages like soundcloud.com using Matlab/R/Python?

Tags: javascript, python, r, matlab, soundcloud

I would like to retrieve a source code of the first N pages from [soundcloud.com/explore](http://soundcloud.com/explore), but the problem is that I have to somehow preload them first.

For now what I do is using some browser and mouse scroll button I preload desired number of pages, then save it as *.html and then parse and analyze using R/Matlab, but it's quite labor-intensive and so I wonder whether there is a way to handle such a situation using some scripting language.

Thanks!

Comment: You should add Javascript to the tags. This "preloading" that you are talking about is nothing more than some Javascript magic of Soundcloud. Instead of using the browser-focused web, have you taken a look into the API https://developers.soundcloud.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, I did look at their API but unfortunately they do not allow to retrieve so-called users' Stream from their pages like this one https://soundcloud.com/drumcode. But one does can get access to so-called users' Likes pages via API.
As of me I have no idea how to handle these Javascript magic of Soundcloud related to Stream pages bypassing API.